# dep0810 microsoft.winjs.1.0 and higher version in my machine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sdk, version

This app references Microsoft.WinJS.1.0, version 1.0.8514.0, found in your SDK, but you have a higher version of Microsoft.WinJS.1.0 installed on the target machine, 1.0.9200.20602. If you continue to run this application, it will run against the currently installed version, Microsoft.WinJS.1.0, version 1.0.9200.20602. Consider updating your SDK to match the version of Microsoft.WinJS.1.0 that is installed.